# how to implement Twilio Programmable Conversations in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

i don't know how can i start Twilio Programmable Conversations in ios swift application and what would be steps for it and there is change this program programmable chat to programmable conversations

and there not open https://www.twilio.com/en-us/changelog/programmable-chat-end-of-life this web site where it given at programmable chat, so please kindly help me to implementation in ios swift

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at iOS Academy tutorial about StreamChat [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFPnIIKpOSw&t=1993s). You still need to handle some parts which were left to be done, such as user authentication, but it's a good starting point. I do prefer Sendbird tho, as it is better documented. These kind of APIs let you build a chat app with minimal coding, the issue tho is that they are **very** expensive.

If you want to take the hard route instead, and learn how a chat service works behind the hood, you can also give a try at [this free course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mroju8T7Gdo&list=PL5PR3UyfTWvdlk-Qi-dPtJmjTj-2YIMMf), again from iOS Academy, where you gonna code a chat app from scratch using Firebase as a backend. Keep in mind that the course cover just the basis, the final product is by no means good for production.

Comment: sorry, but i need to integrate through the Twilio

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Evangelist here.

If you're looking to implement Twilio Conversations API in your iOS Swift app, here are some helpful resources to get you started:

First, make sure to check out the [Exploring the Conversations Swift Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/ios/exploring-conversations-swift-quickstart) guide for iOS. It provides a step-by-step tutorial on how to integrate Conversations API into your Swift project. You can find this guide in the Twilio documentation.

Additionally, if you're already using the Chat iOS SDK and want to migrate to Conversations, Twilio has a handy guide specifically for that purpose. It will help you seamlessly transition your existing Chat functionality to Conversations API.

For a more practical example, I recommend taking a look at the [Twilio Conversations Demo](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-conversations-demo-ios-swift) for iOS. It's a ready-to-use application with Swift code available on GitHub. This demo will give you a real-world example of how to build and implement Conversations in your own iOS app.

I hope these resources help you kickstart your implementation of Twilio Conversations in iOS Swift. If you have any further questions or need clarification, don't hesitate to reach out.

Good luck with your project!